# How to name tag data samples in pandas DataFrame with the name of file from which they were imported?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project in which I am importing many different CSV files, or worksheets as I am calling them, into one pandas DataFrame. The worksheets contain information on many hundreds of different people and I am organizing the DataFrame by one of the columns (which county the person is from), and then exporting all of the data on people from county A to a new CSV file, same for people from county B, etc... I have accomplished all of that successfully, however my problem now is that I would like to create a new column in each of the new files that contains the name of the original worksheet that all of the data samples (people) have come from. For example, if I have exported all of the people from County A (across all of the original worksheets) into a new file called CountyA.csv, how can I add a new column that gives the name of the worksheet that each person originally came from?

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

files_path = '/Users/Desktop/Data/worksheets'
files = glob.glob(files_path + '/*.csv')

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file) for file in files), ignore_index=True)

data = []
for file in files:
    CountyA = df.loc[df['County'] == 'County A']
    CountyA['Worksheet'] = os.path.basename(files)
    data.append(CountyA)
    pd.DataFrame(CountyA).to_csv('CountyA.csv')
    print(pd.DataFrame(CountyA))
```

When I run this, it successfully compiles all of the worksheets into one DataFrame, searches the DataFrame and organizes by county, exports all of the data from people in County A to a new file called CountyA.csv, and creates a new column in the new file called 'worksheets', however, in this new column it does not actually state which worksheet each individual data point is from. It simply makes multiple different new files and in each one it just fills every point in the new column with the name of just one worksheet, rather than showing which worksheet each data point is from. I am hoping someone can help me out!

By the way I am very new to coding and this is my first post on stack overflow, so if any other information would be helpful please let me know and I will do everything I can to provide it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described, your code needs to look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

files_path = '/Users/Desktop/Data/worksheets'
files = glob.glob(files_path + '/*.csv')
ls_temp_dfs = []
for file in files:
  temp_df =  pd.read_csv(file)
  temp_df['WorkSheet'] = os.path.basename(file)
  ls_temp_dfs.append(temp_df)
df_combined = pd.concat(ls_temp_dfs, ignore_index = True)
```

This will ensure that the name of the file is added as a column to each data point. Then if you want to export, you don't need to loop over files. Simply you can do something like this:

```
CountyA = df_combined.loc[df_combined['County'] == 'County A']
CountryA.to_csv('CountyA.csv')
```

Comment: This is perfect! I cannot being to express my thanks to you haha it has been about two full days of me trying to figure this out.

Comment: @valenwood0512 my pleasure. Can you please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark if this answers your question?